# Move php file in PhpStorm, the include path doesn't update

Tags: php, phpstorm

The file tree is like this:

```
./index.php
./conn/conn.php
```

conn.php is included in index.php

```
<?php include("conn/conn.php") ?>
```

When I move the conn.php to another folder using Refactor/Move, the include path doesn't update automatically.
But the Refactor/Rename works fine.
I have checked "Search for references".

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should report a bug to PHPStorm developers if you believe this to be an issue.

Comment: @JoelCox questions about software development tools [are actually on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at Stack Overflow, but this does indeed sound more like a bug report (which is obviously off-topic here).

Comment: @Nic - Thanks for clarifying that point. I admit my comment is somewhat ambiguous about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the drag&drop to move the file. If it don't work, try to restart PHPStorm.

If that doesn't work, try to invalidate the cache (File -> invalid cache / restart).

Otherwise, it must be a bug of PHPStorm. Check if the problem is present in all of your projects and check if an issue is opened on the JetBrains bugtracker. If no issue is opened, open one here : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI